# Adding a log when encounter null object in parallel stream

Tags: java, filter, java-8, stream, java-stream

Not sure about the syntax here, new to lambda expressions and the sort.

```
            itemStream.parallel().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach( 
                (item) -> randomMethod(item));
```

What I had previously in a for loop was a check for null and then a warning if encountered a null item

```
                    log.warn("Skipping a null item!");
```

How do I log when it encounters a null object (while still filtering) with the stream based approach?

Comment: but I have to wonder what is the use of this log in the first place...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Stream::peek`:

```
itemStream.parallel()
    .peek(item -> { if (item == null) log.warn("Skipping a null item!"); })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(item -> randomMethod(item));
```

You can also use a method reference for `randomMethod` (here I assume it's a member of `this`):

```
itemStream.parallel()
    .peek(item -> { if (item == null) log.warn("Skipping a null item!"); })
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(this::randomMethod);
```

Comment: the downside is that the checks happen twice

Comment: @Eugene True, but the logging probably takes at least one or two orders of magnitude longer than the checks.

Comment: @DavidConrad of course... I was just sayin, I even upvoted

Comment: @Eugene Understood. It's a caveat OP should be aware of.

Comment: That’s the time to rethink whether `null` is supposed to be a valid element or not. If it is valid, there is no need to log occurences of `null`. If not, it’s much better to use `.map(Objects::requireNonNull)` and have it fail immediately and go fixing the source, if it happens.

Comment: @Holger Agreed. For myself, I would never allow nulls in there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

With `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` you're filtering out all the `null` elements and only retaining the non-null elements which means in the `forEach` you won't receive any null elements never mind logging it. instead, you want:

```
itemStream.parallel()
          .forEach(item -> { 
               if(Objects.isNull(item)) { ... } else { ... }; // or if(item == null) ...
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

After filtering `null` items you can't find them!

Simply use this:

```
itemStream.parallel().forEach((item)-> {
    if(item==null)
       log.warn("Skipping a null item!");
    else
       randomMethod(item)
});
```